# Could this assembly code that sets the five control registers bits to ones damage my processor?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

A friend sent me that code and alleges that it could damage the processor. Is that true?

```
void damage_processor() {
    while (true) {
        // Assembly code that sets the five control registers bits to ones which causes a bunch of exceptions in the system and then damages the processor
        Asm(
            "mov cr0, 0xffffffff \n\t"
            "mov cr1, 0xffffffff \n\t"
            "mov cr2, 0xffffffff \n\t"
            "mov cr3, 0xffffffff \n\t"
            "mov cr4, 0xffffffff \n\t"
        )
    }
}
```

Is that true?

Comment: Intriguing. I'd be shocked if it were possible to write code to directly damage the processor, but it is certainly possible to create system instability from an application which leads to a total system failure pending a restart.

Comment: Everyone knows HCF is the instruction that destroys your machine.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire

Comment: Related (but by no means the same): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343918/code-that-causes-physical-effects-in-hardware, http://superuser.com/questions/54385/can-a-virus-melt-the-cpu/83290

Comment: If you wanted to destroy a computer, execute the sequence of instructions that reflashes the BIOS but flash something besides the BIOS there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From userspace code? No.  It'll cause a privilege exception and the kernel will terminate your program.  From kernel code?  I doubt it; you will be throwing exceptions, and you'd have to manually set up the fault handler to return to the code in question to keep doing it.  There's also a decent chance you'll cause a triple fault if part of the CR3 move succeeds, since that controls the page table address and you'll probably get faults on instruction fetch, handler fetch, and then the double fault handler fetch.  The CPU should just shut down if that happens.

Check the Intel or AMD manuals for Systems programming, they'll tell you which exceptions will be thrown when writing invalid bits to the control registers.

Comment: Triple faults usually trigger a reboot.

Comment: The double fault handler fetch should come from a task gate anyway, with a "safe" CR3 value for the CPU to load along with safe stacks and register values. Smashing CR3 "shouldn't" triple-fault the system (theoretically), but it's still not a good idea.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe if you let it run for about 20 years.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this code causes your processor/system to lock up but there is no chance that it damages it permanently.

Imagine if this were true: it would immediately be used by viruses/trojans to attack computers or hide their activity after detection.

Even in the case that any code could damage a processor, the processor manufacturer could issue a so called microcode-update which is something like a soft-fix for the processor. Such microcode-updates are provided by operating systems and/or BIOS (and processor manufacturers) and are loaded into the processor before such code could be executed.

To sum it up: No, your friend is wrong, assuming we're talking about x86/x64 platforms.

Answer (score 5):

No.  If the point is to feverishly excercise the processor in hopes of breaking it, computer systems have thermal solutions (fans, copper heat exchangers, heat sinks, etc.) to prevent overheating.  In the event of a failure in the thermal solution, the BIOS will assert #THERMTRIP and turn off the machine.

Answer (score 2):

This won't even assemble; the source operand for `mov`-to-control-register has to be a GPR, not an immediate or memory.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-1).  It also won't compile; the keyword in GNU C is `asm()` not `Asm()`.

So no, *this* code can't do anything because it's not encodeable into machine code, so there's nothing for an x86 CPU to execute.

Also, [CR1 is reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#Control_registers_in_Intel_x86_series); `mov cr1, eax` (32-bit mode) or `mov cr1, rax` (64-bit mode) will #UD illegal-instruction fault.

And CR3 is the top-level page-table pointer, so setting it will likely result in code-fetch starting somewhere else unless the page at physical address `0xFFFFF000` is a useful top-level page-directory with a mapping for the current RIP or EIP.  (PML4 in 64-bit mode, or whatever it's called in PAE mode.)  The writes to other control registers will enable PAE if we were in legacy mode, so it had better have already been enabled, since it's even more unlikely that the same page will work as both a legacy page directory for 32-bit 2-level tables and as a top-level PAE table.  (The low 12 bits are either ignored or are a PCID = Process Context ID.)

**Whoever sent you this code was just making stuff up.  It's not even plausible as pseudo-code for using a temporary register for the `-1` value.**

---

If we remove the CR1 write and make real code that uses a temporary register so it could actually execute, it still won't damage your hardware even if run in kernel mode.  e.g. `mov rax, -1` / `mov cr0, rax` / ....  Or to match the code better, I guess perhaps they `mov eax, -1` / `mov cr0, rax` to zero-extend those 32-bit zeros.  (64-bit mode can only do a 64-bit `mov` to/from control regs.  Legacy 32-bit mode can only do 32-bit `mov` to/from them.)

It might crash your machine and force a reboot. (Or directly lead to reboot via triple-fault, if it reaches the part where it sets CR3, the top-level page-table, to all-ones, if that's not a valid physical address or that page isn't a useful top-level page table.)

If that new value for CR3 points to a page table such that CS:RIP still points at the next instruction, the write to CR4 will definitely raise a `#GP(0)` exception, [as documented in Intel's manuals](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-1#protected-mode-exceptions) for protected or 64-bit mode.

> #### Protected Mode Exceptions ¶
>
> ###### `#GP(0)` (General Protection fault):
>
> - If the current privilege level is not 0.  ([aka kernel mode required]
> - If an attempt is made to write invalid bit combinations in CR0 (such as setting the PG flag to 1 when the PE flag is set to 0, or setting the CD flag to 0 when the NW flag is set to 1).
> - **If an attempt is made to write a 1 to any reserved bit in CR4.**
> - If an attempt is made to write 1 to CR4.PCIDE.  [*that's ok in 64-bit mode, but not legacy protected mode*]
> - If any of the reserved bits are set in the page-directory pointers table (PDPT) and the loading of a control register causes the PDPT to be loaded into the processor.
>
> ###### `#UD` (illegal-instruction exception):
>
> - If the LOCK prefix is used.
> - **If an attempt is made to access CR1**, CR5, CR6, CR7, or CR9–CR15.

The write to CR0 might not fault; setting all the bits might not be an invalid combination.  This code wasn't worth any more effort in proving that it's nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I heard rumor of a bug in the Pentium I that when given a certain nonsensical series of instructions in a tight loop would burn up a single flip-flop so fast the thermal protection couldn't protect it.

What I found reference for once was really old CPUs could be cooked by doing this in real mode:

```
halt:
    jmp short halt
```

The correct* code was

```
halt:
    nop
    jmp short halt
```

<sup>* This answer is written as a near quote of the old material. You really should use a `hlt` instruction.</sup>

Comment: Could you also provide the reference to us?

Comment: I sincerely doubt that.  AFAIK Pentium 1 had no thermal protection.  Additionally, any Intel-approved heatsink would be more than sufficient to keep the core temp in check even with the max power draw.  http://www.intel.com/design/pentium/datashts/24199710.pdf

Comment: The correct 8086 code to halt with idling, which can cool a processor compared to running an empty loop, is `halt:` \ `hlt` \ `jmp halt`

Comment: @ecm: Yes, yes it was. In the 386 this didn't save any power.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the code doesn't run on an ARM processor.

In many processors, instructions that set the status word or affect the processor are restricted to "supervisor" mode.  Good operating systems run User code in a "protected" mode that does not have the same capabilities as "supervisor" mode.  Executing privileged instructions on modern processors in User mode generates exceptions.

You and your friend could always look up the instructions in an assembly language reference manual and verify the operation.

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is unlikely to do much except reboot the machine. In my experience, an x86 CPU could be bricked by executing software code.