# Can a program harm your computer?

Tags: assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to permanently damage the hardware by software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286425/is-it-possible-to-permanently-damage-the-hardware-by-software)

Browsing the mono sources I stumbled uppon this comment:

```
/* don't run the resulting program, it will destroy your computer,
 * just objdump -d it to inspect we generated the correct assembler.
 */
```

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/arch/x86/test.c

What harm can it do?

Comment: Try compiling it and running an anti-virus program on the resulting binary. The programs have heuristics that may catch whatever it is that this thing is doing, and I'd expect them to report it to you.

Comment: Do you mean physically harm it? Sure, you can wear computers down by running resource-intensive programs.

Comment: Hardware, that can be destroyed by software, deserves destroying.

Comment: a person would need to know what's going on in `x86-codegen.h`

Comment: @Yossarian Just flash the BIOS of your PC with some random data. It deserves it, as you say

Comment: In general yes, you can harm your computer with software, is it easy or trivial?  Not necessarily.

Comment: why does this have an assembly tag?